# Parameterizable customer object in Tinkercad

Tags: tinkercad

**Background**: Basic shapes in Tinkercad have parameters like Sides, Segments, ... (see screenshot below).

Using codeblocks one can create custom shape. Within the code it is possible to define variables which can be used as a parameters based on which shape is created. This is not flexible solution because if I want to modify some variable I need to enter codeblock, change the value, export to Tinkercad and then I can use it.

**Question**: Is there a way to create custom object with parameters controlled from Tinkercad like in case of basic shapes?

[image: Parameters]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a way in Tinkercad. It is called a shape generator and it is very well hidden. you can find it here:

- Open Tinkercad and select a model to Tinker or create a new one.
- select the "Basic shapes" pulldown on the right and choose the last option: "shape generators".
- choose "create shape generator"
- choose "new shape generator" and select a template to start from
  Here you have the javascript code to create a shape with parameters like basic shapes.

Comment: Unfortunatelly shape generators access has been limited. Authors encourage to use codeblocks instead. You can read more here: https://tinkercad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360035611434-Attention-Tinkercad-to-limit-access-to-the-Shape-Generator-code-editor-for-new-users

Comment: That's a shame to hear. Let's hope that codeblocks matures before the JS scripting is disabled.